# How to Determine The Partition Size in an Apache Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have been using an excellent answer to a question posted on SE here to determine the number of partitions, and the distribution of partitions across a dataframe
[Need to Know Partitioning Details in Dataframe Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217964/need-to-know-partitioning-details-in-dataframe-spark/39220497#39220497)

Can someone help me expand on answers to determine the partition size of dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: instead of determine the partition size, you should determine the number of partition. according to documentation, the recommended number is [2,4] * total number of cores

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tuning the **partition size** is inevitably, linked to tuning the **number of partitions**. There're at least 3 factors to consider in this scope:

#### Level of parallelism

A "good" high level of parallelism is important, so you may want to have a big number of partitions, resulting in a small partition size.

However, there is an upper bound of the number due to the following 3rd point - **distribution overhead**. Nevertheless, it's still ranked priority #1, so let's say if you have to make a mistake, start with the side of high level of parallelism.

Generally, it's recommended 2 to 4 tasks per core.

- [Spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/tuning.html#level-of-parallelism):

> *In general, we recommend 2-3 tasks per CPU core in your cluster.*

- The book **Spark in action** (author Petar Zecevi´c) writes (page 74):

> *We recommend using three to four times more partitions than there are cores in your cluster*

#### Memory fitting

If partition size is very large (e.g. > 1 GB), you may have issues such as garbage collection, out of memory error, etc., especially when there's shuffle operation, as per [Spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/tuning.html#memory-usage-of-reduce-tasks):

> *Sometimes, you will get an OutOfMemoryError, not because your RDDs don’t fit in memory, but because the working set of one of your tasks, such as one of the reduce tasks in groupByKey, was too large. Spark’s shuffle operations (sortByKey, groupByKey, reduceByKey, join, etc) build a hash table within each task to perform the grouping, which can often be large...*

Hence here comes another pros of big number of partitions (or, small partition size).

#### Distribution overhead

Distributed computing comes with overhead, so you can't go to an extreme either. If each task takes less than 100ms to execute, the application might have remarkable overhead due to:

- data fetches, disk seeks
- data movement, tasks distributing
- task state tracking

, in which case you may lower the level of parallelism and increase partition size a bit.

**Take-away**

Empirically, people usually try with 100-1000MB per partition, so why not start with that? And remember that the number may need to re-tuned along the time..

Comment: thanks for reaching out. Can you let me know if there is any pyspark code that I could appy to find out the partition size?

Comment: sure, what about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068112/spark-find-each-partition-size-for-rdd?

Comment: Brilliant, I jus visited the link, and it looks like what I need. Thanks again