# How to decide the better spark.sql.shuffle.partitions number for a spark job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My daily spark application process all the datalake steps, starting by process the raw layer(deduplication and etl functions),creation of DW and Datamarts ...
When I start the sparkSession, I cannot decide what is the better configuration of **spark.sql.shuffle.partitions** value.
My cluster configuration :

- 7 Active Nodes
- 738.50 GB Memory Total
- Spark version 2.1.0

My question is: How to choose the better value of **spark.sql.shuffle.partitions** to gain performance in my spark job.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's **no standard** answer of it. But in general, **start with a high level of parallelism** first (i.e. big nb. of partitions).

It's recommended 2 to 4 tasks per core.

- [Spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/tuning.html#level-of-parallelism):

> *In general, we recommend 2-3 tasks per CPU core in your cluster.*

So in your example, 7 nodes, and you need to know the number of cores, as each node can have multiple executors and each executor can have multiple cores.

Regarding memory, it depends on how big your data set is, and what kind of operation you're doing, whether the data is skewed, etc.

And.. why not try with the latest Spark which brings you more optimization already? :)

Related **answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64600212/how-to-determine-the-partition-size-in-an-apache-spark-dataframe/64617126#64617126)**.